# React Native firebase function doesn't fetch correctly under useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am using react native and firebase firestore on a project.

I want to fetch some data of the post in the post screen, and when I try to fetch it, it doesn't work from the first try. I'm using useEffect to avoid infinite loops and I added a console.log to see what really happens.

What should happen: the firebase.firestore()...get() should retrieve the data of the post from firestore in an object inside an array. However, when using useEffect, the first time it's unsuccessful. I set a console.log after the whole fetch to check if the arr.length !== 0 and I can clearly see that arr.length === 0.

However, here is the weird thing, If I let the useEffect run indefinitely, from the 2nd try on it retrieves the data good. Any ideas on how things can be solved?

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);


        useEffect(() => {

            
    
            firebase.firestore()
            .collection("allPosts")
            .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data }
                })
                setPost(data)
            })

            if (post.length !== 0) {
                console.log('Worked')
            } else {
                console.log('Empty')

                
            } 
                            
    
        }, [])
```

EDIT:
const [post, setPost] = useState(null);

```
useEffect(() => {

            
    
            // 1
            firebase.firestore()
            .collection("allPosts")
            .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {

              //2
                let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data }

                
                })
                setPost(data)

                 //3
            if (data.length !== 0) {
                console.log('Worked')
                
            } else {
                console.log('Empty')

                
            } 

            console.log(post)
            })
            

           
                            
    
        }, [])
```

The console log of data.length returns worked, the console log of post(last) returns null. That's what I don't understand, why?

Answer (score 0):

The code is behaving as it should. You should move the `console.log` into the `then`. The wait it's now it will be executed in this order:

```js
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  // 1
  firebase.firestore()
    .collection("allPosts")
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      //3
      let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const id = doc.id;
        return {
          id,
          ...data
        }
      })
      setPost(data)
    })

  //2
  if (post.length !== 0) {
    console.log('Worked')
  } else {
    console.log('Empty')
  }
}, [])
```

That is the reason you don't see any that in the first try. The `console.log` is executed before the async data is loaded from firestore.

Change your code to this to make it work as expected:

```js
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  // 1
  firebase.firestore()
    .collection("allPosts")
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      //2
      let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const id = doc.id;
        return {
          id,
          ...data
        }
      })
      setPost(data)

      //3
      if (data.length !== 0) {
        console.log('Worked')
      } else {
        console.log('Empty')
      }
    })
}, [])
```

You could also use another `useEffect` to log the changed data:

```js
  useEffect(()=>{
          if (post.length !== 0) {
                console.log('Worked')
            } else {
                console.log('Empty')

                
            } 
        },[post])
```

Or just log it directly in the render function.

EDIT:

```
const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  // 1
  firebase.firestore()
    .collection("allPosts")
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      //2
      let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const id = doc.id;
        return {
          id,
          ...data
        }
      })
      setPost(data)
      //3
      if (data.length !== 0) {
        console.log('Worked')

      } else {
        console.log('Empty')
      }

      console.log(post)
    })
}, [])
```

The console log of data.length returns worked, the console log of post(last) returns null. That's what I don't understand, why?

Comment: What did you change in the 2nd 'good' code?

Comment: I just moved the console.log into the `then`. Sound trivial but it makes a huge difference when you use `async/await`

Comment: Apparently it is an error from rn-firebase, it has to fetch more than once to get the data. Spoke to others that had this error. The weird thing that fixed it for me was to useState of post as ([0]) rather than ([]) -> extremely weird. And also use useEffect and another state to check if loaded and pass that state as 2nd arg for useEffect

Comment: I don't want to be rude. But your code (from the question) can't work as you expect it to. That is 100% not a bug from Firebase. I don't know who you asked but they should also learn a little bit more about `async/await`.  Here is even an example almost the same as your code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Edited the post with your code. Still, the last console.log returns null. PS: My mistake, edited your post instead of mine. Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: The reason is now a missunderstanding of `react`. When your `useEffect` runs and you call `setPost` you can't console.log `post` directly after that and expect to see the change. If you notice I also did not use `post` but `data` in the log.

Comment: I understand this now. Excuse me please, I am new to react. My goal is just to be able to render fields from that object that I got, but I keep getting an error in return() that post.field is undefined even tho it exists. And I can't find a proper solution. It should be extremely basic

Comment: You don't need to excuse yourself. We are all here to help each other. If you want to use `post` you can just make a console.log directly in your React function component or use it in the html part of your component.